# Control all user traffic to Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, security

We are working on a gateway solution aimed for Sharepoint Online to control all user traffic and possibly, do changes on requests and responses.

Is there any way to enforce/limit connections to Sharepoint only through a certain gateway?

We've found ADFS proxy but we're not sure if that only handles authentication or the whole communication between the user and Office 365.